# C# 7.0 standalone discard confusion

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I would like to better understand a couple of examples involving the usage of C# 7.0 discard feature.

Both of them make use of the so called [stand alone discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#a-standalone-discard).

This is the first example confusing me, which is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread):

```
public class EmailController
{
    public ActionResult SendEmail(string email)
    {
        var correlationId = HttpContext.Request.Headers["x-correlation-id"].ToString();

        // Starts sending an email, but doesn't wait for it to complete
        _ = SendEmailCore(correlationId);
        return View();
    }

    private async Task SendEmailCore(string correlationId)
    {
        // send the email
    }
}
```

Is the standalone discard used when calling `SendEmailCore` useful in any way ? What's the difference between the code above and the same code **without** the assignment of `SendEmailCore(correlationId)` to the discard expression `_` ? Is there any difference in the runtime behavior ?

Here is the second code example, which is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#a-standalone-discard):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      ExecuteAsyncMethods().Wait();
   }

   private static async Task ExecuteAsyncMethods()
   {    
      Console.WriteLine("About to launch a task...");
      _ = Task.Run(() => { var iterations = 0;  
                           for (int ctr = 0; ctr < int.MaxValue; ctr++)
                              iterations++;
                           Console.WriteLine("Completed looping operation...");
                           throw new InvalidOperationException();
                         });
      await Task.Delay(5000);                        
      Console.WriteLine("Exiting after 5 second delay");
   }
}
```

Again, I can't see the usefulness of the assignment to the discard expression `_`, I tried the example in visual studio, but it seems that the runtime behavior is the same with and without the discard expression. 
Furthermore, in the example description there is the following sentence that confuses me even more:

> The following example uses a standalone discard to ignore the Task
>   object returned by an asynchronous operation. This has the effect of
>   suppressing the exception that the operation throws as it is about to
>   complete.

The exception raised inside the call to `Task.Run` is ignored by the runtime in any case, in the sense that the program completes successfully **with or without** the discard expression.

This is **not** related to the discard expression itself, but to the fact that the returned task is abandoned and its exception is not observed. The task is not awaited and there is not a call to `Task.Wait`, so the CLR ignores the exception and the process doesn't crash; this is the usual Task behavior since .NET 4.5. So what is the point of the quoted sentence ?

Comment: `SendEmailCore(correlationId);` may appear due to the programmer not realizing something is being returned. `_ = SendEmailCore(correlationId);` makes it clear that the programmer knows about the return value and does not want it.

Comment: Well, i am not affiliated with the documentation team, nor do i have any relation or connection with the language and compiler architects for C#. But this is not the only place where the documentation struggles/struggled to explain a feature (discards) that outside of tuple deconstruction feels seemingly purposeless (see here for a discussion with regard to another "useless" use case of discards: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8727, but which has been removed/altered from the documentation since then...)

Comment: @GSerg so the only purpose of the assignment is making clear that the returned `Task` object it's not interesting and that we are aware that we have started an operation in a *fire and forget* mode ?

Comment: @GSerg, since `_` could also be a valid variable identifier, using it like that is not so clear after all, and probably just adds to confusion unless using `_` as a variable identifer would be outlawed...

Comment: @EnricoMassone Arguably, yes. You can never know for sure.

Comment: It's weird that they would use this as an example in official documentation. btw, in IL, there is no difference. With or without the discard, it compiles the same.

Comment: @GSerg what about the second example and the quoted sentence from the documentation ? The sentece, based on my understanding of tasks and exceptions, is completely confusing. Am I correct when I say that it is **not** the discard expression that allows the process to complete successfully, but instead it's the standard behavior of tasks since .NET 4.5 ?

Comment: @EnricoMassone Yes. The exception is ignored because the returned Task is not `await`ed, not because it was assigned to a discard variable.

Comment: Answering questions about the meaning/intent of the documentation is clearly "primarily opinion-based", unless you get lucky and the author of the documentation sees and answers your question. As far as use of discard generally in these scenarios, it's been my experience that without them, calling methods that return values without doing anything with those values generates a compile-time warning. You can cause the warning to be suppressed by assigning the value to something, and a discard is a convenient thing to use for that purpose. Are you not seeing a warning without the discard?

Comment: If you think there is an error, you can open an issue and have the documentation team look at it.

Comment: @NetMage I opened [an issue on the documentation github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13239) in order to better understand