# C# 7.0 standalone discard confusion | difference between _ = FooTask() and _ = Task.Run(FooTask)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-7.0

I have a `Task` `FooTask` which should be called in background. A new feature in `C# 7.0` is the `discard` function. As already asked ([C# 7.0 standalone discard confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875049/c-sharp-7-0-standalone-discard-confusion)) it is possible to call the `Task` in two ways. However, I have not yet been able to find out exactly how these two calls differ and whether they make a difference at all.

```cs
_ = Task.Run(FooTask);
```

```cs
_ = FooTask();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Discards make no difference here whatsoever; your code is identical to:

```
Task.Run(FooTask);
```

```
FooTask();
```

Even the generated IL is identical.

Discards simply make explicit that the returned `Task` is not required for any further process.

> However, I have not yet been able to find out exactly how these two calls differ and whether they make a difference at all

The difference is the use of `Task.Run` which forces `FooTask` to run on a ThreadPool thread.

Without `Task.Run`, `FooTask` will run on the current thread until a continuation is scheduled, and the thread on which that continuation resumes is determined by the synchronisation context.

Comment: Part about garbage colleciton is a bit confusing. Discards make explicit in code that YOU, the developer, do not care about the return value. As you said yourself - IL is identical, so it has no effect or relation to garbage collection.